# Classical Mechanics - Potential Energy Function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, stability

**Question**

The potential energy function of a particle of mass $m$ is: 
$$V(x) = \frac{cx}{x^2+a^2}$$
where c and a are positive constants.

Qualitatively sketch $V$ as a function of $x$.

Find two equilibrium points: identify which is a position of stable equilibrium, and find the period of small oscillations about it.

**Progress**

I think I'm supposed to differentiate and let it equal to zero which gave me:

$$\frac{c(x^2+a^2) - 2cx^2}{(x^2+a^2)^2} = 0$$

$$cx^2 + ca^2 - 2cx^2 = 0$$

$$x = a$$

Putting that into the function gave me: $$V(x) = \frac{cx^2}{2x^2} = c/2$$

I don't know if any of this is necessary but it doesn't answer the question. Also when it says sketch do I just sub values of x in ie. 1,2,3? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a long time since I had to sketch a function, but IIRC the steps were: (a) differentiate to find the extrema (b) differentiate again to establish if they are maxima or minima (c) find the zeros (d) find the beaviour at infinity. Once you've got this it's easy to draw a rough sketch of the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not quite a full answer to your homework problem here (our [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) actually forbids detailed answers), but it should be enough to guide you to your answer.

---

Note first that, formally, the solution to
$$
cx^2+ca^2-2cx^2=0
$$
is
$$
x=\color{red}{\pm} a
$$
This indicates that there are *two* local minima/maxima points. Inserting these into $V(x)$ should give you the value of the potential there:
$$
V(x=\pm a)=\frac{c\left(\pm a\right)}{a^2+a^2}=\pm\frac{c}{2a}
$$
The fact there's a positive and negative value shows that there's one minima and one maxima.

For sketching $V(x)$, it requires a bit of intuition about the function itself. Consider how $V(x)$ behaves for $|x|\ll a$ and for $|x|\gg a$. You also know that there's a maxima at $x=a$, a minima at $x=-a$, and a zero at $x=0$.

Stability analysis requires taking the second derivative of $V(x)$, $V''(x)$:

- if $V''(x)\vert_{x=\pm a} < 0$ it is an **unstable** point (i.e., local maximum)
- if $V''(x)\vert_{x=\pm a} > 0$ it is a **stable** point (i.e., local minimum)

Once you have this, you can [Taylor expand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) about the stable equilibrium point $b$:
$$
V(x)\vert_{x=b}=V(b)+V'(b)x+\frac12V''(b)x^2+\cdots
$$
since $V'(b)=0$ by definition. If you ignore all higher terms that aren't written above, this can look somewhat like the [simple harmonic potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Simple_harmonic_oscillator): $U(x)=\frac12 kx^2$, which we should all know & love. From this comparison, the period should be straight forward.